# What is the function for the KMP Failure Algorithm?

Tags: string, algorithm, knuth-morris-pratt

What is the proper functions that tell us the KMP failure table?

I have looked at a couple but they are very confusing. I am getting a bit confused with the suffixes and the prefixes and how to match them ?

I believe we start with `-1` and `0` but I can't seem to understand the rest of the table.

Comment: What is the "KMP failure table"? I don't believe it's a common term. Perhaps you should either explain it or link to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the aho-corasick algorithm and the failure function is computed with a breadth-first-traversal of the trie. You walk each level and each children first with a queue.

Comment: I didn't ask for that :P I'd need an answer which walks through the kMP failure function !

Comment: Aho-corasick is the generalized form of kmp algorithm.